# USB-Stick doesn't work with Mouse

Tags: mouse, 15.10, dell, usb-drive

I hope you guys can help me with this:

**System**

- Kingston R30G2 DataTraveler
- Dell Mouse & Keyboard (Wireless)
- Dell XPS 12 Laptop
- Ubuntu 15.10

**Problem**

If I plug the stick in, the external mouse stops working, while the keyboard (same receiver) still works. If I plug in a cable mouse, it works just fine as well. Using Windows 10, the wireless mouse works as well.

**Syslog**

of pluging in and out

```
[ 6543.616425] usb 3-1.4.3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 6543.643295] usb 3-1.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16a2
[ 6543.643303] usb 3-1.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6543.643307] usb 3-1.4.3: Product: DTR30G2
[ 6543.643310] usb 3-1.4.3: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 6543.643313] usb 3-1.4.3: SerialNumber: 0018F30C9FDCB010710CE065
[ 6543.646228] usb-storage 3-1.4.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6543.646379] scsi host4: usb-storage 3-1.4.3:1.0
[ 6543.748569] [UFW BLOCK] IN=lxcbr0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2a02:8070:04af:fc00:bd5b:b6b0:ccfd:bfbe DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=17500 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[ 6543.748588] [UFW BLOCK] IN=lxcbr0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2a02:8070:04af:fc00:bd5b:b6b0:ccfd:bfbe DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=337015 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[ 6544.645428] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DTR30G2          PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 6544.646281] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 6545.291192] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 122880000 512-byte logical blocks: (62.9 GB/58.5 GiB)
[ 6545.292081] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 6545.292085] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 6545.292984] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 6545.292997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6545.296495]  sdc: sdc1
[ 6545.299944] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 6552.535050] usb 3-1.4.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 6552.768873] [UFW BLOCK] IN=lxcbr0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2a02:8070:04af:fc00:bd5b:b6b0:ccfd:bfbe DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=17500 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the keyboard and mouse connect to a single USB dongle?

Comment: Can you try different USB port combinations? For example, if you're on a desktop PC that has USB ports on the front, plug the dongle there, and the keyboard/mouse receiver in the ports on the back of the computer case. (mostly, the idea is to use USB ports that are not adjacent to each other, and see if the problem persists)

Comment: @TheSchwa, yes, one dongle.

Comment: @Dan I only have a laptop with two ports, tried both combinations. I tried it with a hub as well (a good one that never made any problems before)

Comment: I just added the syslog of pluging in and out, if that helps. I don't see anything strange, though.